# Processing Resources failed with error: Duplicate Entry

Tags: c#, uwp, projects-and-solutions

I have a UWP project that is failing with these errors: 
[image: Errors]

I know this is pretty vague, but I don't have much.  Here is what I did:

- I made sure I only have `en-US` as my language everywhere (See warning).
- I searched all non-generated code for `SplitViewPanelItem.xbf`, couldn't find any.
- I scoured the internet for all of the errors, and couldn't find anything that was relevant to this case.

I'll update with any info I find.

Comment: I could not reproduce your issue with your description. Could you mind to share a sample?

Comment: I tried stripping down the project so that it ran without some references, but after that it rebuilt fine.  I wish I could share the code that was faulty, so that the issue could be fixed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find the issue, so I just recreated the project, manually adding back code and changing settings back to how they were.